# Too many Tags in questions titles

Tags: support, tags, title

I know one of the SE policies is not to put the tag name in the title. However I see it all the time. Here is a screen shoot I took. Of the top 8 questions, 7 had the tag in the title. Is there way to enforce this policy?

Ironically enough, this question may violate the policy (see title and tag)?

[image: Tag names in title]

Comment: Sometimes you can't avoid it (like this question), which is why I think it's not enforced that often.

Comment: Out of the examples you highlighted, the first three and #6 are the subpar titles,   with a tag *artificially attached* to the title. The #4 and #5 fit organically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more of a guideline than a hard and fast rule.

A question title should read, well, like a question. If that means including what would be the main tag in the question then that's OK. It's far better to have a title that reads well and tells future visitors what the question is about than something contrived that missed out what may well be the most important piece of information.

For SEO purposes SE adds the main tag *if it's not already there* so there's nothing to worry about on that score.