# How to write code in the title

Tags: support, formatting

Quick typographical/convention question,

**How are we supposed to use programming keywords in the title?** E.g.:

- What does `this` mean?
- What does "this" mean?
- What does this mean?
- Other?

*(not the third one obviously)*

**Edit: My question is not about markup, but about typography**

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: I can't do what?

Comment: You can't render code in question titles.

Comment: What πάνταῥεῖ means is that you can't format code in titles, though it looks like you are more asking how you should "highlight" it in titles, correct?

Comment: don't. Instead, create a meaningful title and a short summary at the top of the question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not trying to render code with a gray background, just to differentiate keywords and actual words. Like in the example I used: it would be confusing not to indicate it

Comment: Just to be sure: Don't ask that question (about the this keyword, especially in JavaScript) on the main site. It'll be a duplicate of many questions.

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: If your question is "What does _this_ mean?" then your question is probably already off-topic. If you're absolutely sure that it's _not_ off-topic then consider a title like "Understanding certain keywords in [language]" and then explain in your question (where you _can_ format) which keyword(s) you're interested in.

Comment: Let me say this one more time guys: it's an example

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Quotation marks are used in English to distinguish [using a word as an object rather than for its meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction), so the second is a good start: "What does 'this' mean?"

But that still needs more work to be actually clear and a good title. Including some other words for context would be important in your example: "What does the term 'this' mean inside of a Java method?"

Comment: Great answer. Of course, the example I used is unclear but you got the point

Comment: Nice compromise. "What does 'f a' mean?" is easier to understand than "What does f a mean?" and prettier than "What does \`f a\` mean?".

Comment: Probably better to say "What does the term 'this' mean inside a method?" since java is (or at least should be) already in the tags.

Comment: I would argue for just "inside a method", since we discourage users from putting the language in the title and use tags for that instead.

Comment: The rule is not "information that appears in the tags must not appear in the title ", @MatthieuM, it's "don't force tags into the title". http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286766 In this case, including the word "Java" is important to distinguish the hypothetical title from the same question about any other language that has methods and uses the keyword `this`.